# Documents Directory Saving Images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an application that saves images to the documents directory.  I have been doing some reading, and I have heard developers applications have been rejected for storing too much data in the documents directory.

I know I can exclude the pictures from the iCloud backup, but I wanted a way for user's to backup their pictures.  This application will likely be a free app, so I do not want to run a server to hold backups.

Any ideas or suggestions on a way to backup the user's photos?

Comment: How much data are you looking to store?  Depending on the function of you saving that data it may be applicable to store the content in the documents directory.

Comment: It depends on how many items, the user will add, and how large the pictures will be.

Comment: If it's user created content, and the user has the ability to also remove content, then storing content there would make sense.  I haven't found any issues in the past with saving to that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with storing lots and lots of data and files in the Documents directory. The requirement is that the data / files must be actual user data that can't be easily replaced if lost. If the photos exist no where else and the photos come from the user using the app, you will be fine.

In other words, don't store content that can be re-downloaded from your server for example.

Comment: "In other words, don't store content that can be re-downloaded from your server for example."- well do so if its meant  to be stored as such (for offline access for example)...

Comment: @Daniel If the content can be replaced by re-downloading it, it should be stored in the Caches directory, not the Documents directory.

Comment: true, missed that we are talking about Documents directory

Answer (score 0):

I think,You have to give limit the number of downloads & saving that images & after limit is completed.delete previous save new one..